# Can people perform major modifications to an aircraft without an A/P license, as long as their company is certified per part 145?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-certification, airframe-and-powerplant, modifications

If a company is part 145 certified wanted to do a major modification, can they do so without having A/Ps? Or does an A/P need to be present to verify/sign off? or no A/P's need to be present?

At that point who would do verifications (if the company was certified per 145)?

Comment: It seems painfully obvious to me that part of the 145 certification process would be ensuring and maintaining a requirement that only qualified mechanics perform the work.  (perhaps with allowances for supervised apprentices...)  Why do you think it would be another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "does an A/P need to be present to verify/sign off? If you meant that they need to be present the whole time during the modification/Repair then the answer is no. A mechanic without an A/P can do modification/repairs, but they need a certified mechanic to verify/sign off their work.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely find all the answers in [14 CFR Part 145 - Repair Stations](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-H/part-145).

But to provide a somewhat qualified and summarized answer to your question:

Per **Subpart D - Personnel**:

- The stations is required to have an Accountable Manager, responsible
  to ensure an adequately trained and certificated staff is in place to
  do the work.
- Supervisory personnel directly in charge of all the work to be done
  and which are required to be certificated as a mechanic or repairman
  under Part 65. Individuals performing the work under that supervision
  must be trained, but are not required to be certificated.
- Properly trained inspection personnel.
- A person certificated as a mechanic or repairman under Part 65
  authorized to approve an article for return to service.
- If they choose to use repairmen, they must certify that the each
  person recommended to receive a repairman certificate, a) Is employed
  by the station, and b) meets the eligibility of Part 65.101.

You might want to also review [Part 65 Subpart D - Mechanics](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-65/subpart-D?toc=1) and [Part 65 Subpart E - Repairmen](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-65/subpart-D?toc=1) to understand the difference.

As a note to the second bullet above; from **§ 145.3 Definition of Terms**:

> (c) **Directly in charge** means having the responsibility for the work
> of a certificated repair station that performs maintenance, preventive
> maintenance, alterations, or other functions affecting aircraft
> airworthiness. A person directly in charge does not need to physically
> observe and direct each worker constantly but must be available for
> consultation on matters requiring instruction or decision from higher
> authority.